# How can I use multi thread in Qt/c++ to access my data base with an Api?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a problem, I'm connecting my program to the data base with an Api, to do this I use the  network and webkit webkitwidgets funtions in Qt. I have been able to do this without any problem.

The think it's that I have to call some funtions in the api class from different threads.

Firts I try passing the api object to the Qthread class, but I'm getting this error:

```
@QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is SerialPort(0x24a1738), parent's thread is QThread(0x24a1770), current thread is QThread(0x18a8b0)
```

So I try ussing signals ans slots, it work with the firts function I use, a funtion to create what a call in my data base a log, but when I try to close the log, so I can send the information needed. I get this error:

```
 QEventLoop::exec: instance xxxxxx has already called exec()
```

What is the best way to work with Threads to avoid this problems ??

Comment: Make a worker class and move it to a QThread. When you want DB access, send a signal to the worker and wait for it to send a signal back.

Comment: You can set the thread of an object that you create. You can also use different means of signal/slot passing, with it being direct (the slot will be called in the same thread) or delayed (the slot will be called when possible with a copy of your arguments in its correct thread) which is the default. With a concrete, minimal code example, we could easily point out the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any code, only error messages.  Since I have to guess, I'll say that you're creating a `QObject`-derived worker object and using the `QObject::moveToThread` method to change its thread affinity.  The problem in this case is that you've already given the worker object a parent.  You can't use `moveToThread` on an object that already has a parent.  So, don't set the parent of your worker object when you create it and you should be good-to-go.

As others users have commented, you will need to use signals & slots to initiate queries, etc. in your worker object.  Qt will handle synchronization issues via the thread's event loop, so you don't have to worry about mutex locking, etc (as long as you use only sig/slot to invoke methods and get output values from the worker object).

Don't forget to call `QThread::start` to get the thread's event loop started.

NOTE 1:  I assume you're using a fairly recent version of Qt (>= 4.8).

NOTE 2:  If you're using `QSqlDatabase` and friends to access your DB, make sure to create the DB connection in the worker object *after* it is moved to the new thread.